# Maximal subsets of affine or projective space with no three collinear points

Tags: co.combinatorics, finite-fields

Let ${\mathbb A}^n_q$ and ${\mathbb P}^n_q$ be affine and projective spaces of dimension $n$ over a field of order $q$.

Say that a subset of either ${\mathbb A}^n_q$ or ${\mathbb P}^n_q$ is *generic* if it does not contain three collinear points.

Question 1:  What is the maximal cardinality of a generic subset of ${\mathbb A}^n_q$?

Question 2:  What is the maximal cardinality of a generic subset of ${\mathbb P}^n_q$?

Question 3:  In the absence of explicit formulas, is there a source for computations with specific (presumably small) values of $n$ and $q$?

Comment: In the projective plane, $k$ points with no $3$ collinear span $\binom{k}{2}$ lines whose union has $(q+1)\binom{k}{2}-\binom{\binom{k}{2}}{2}$ points. If that doesn’t fill up the plane then we can keep adding points outside the union. So solve for $k$ in that expression $=q^2+q+1$.

Comment: @ZachTeitler:  I don't quite follow.  There are $C(k,2)$ lines, with (naively) $(q+1)C(k,2)$ points, which needs to be corrected for double counting.  But I don't understand your $C(C(k,2),2))$ term for the double-counts.  Each pair of lines has a point of intersection, which (naively) gives me $C(k,2)$ double-counts, but some of these might coincide, and I'd have expected the number of coincidences to depend on the exact configuration.  So I'm surprised to see an explicit formula that does not depend on the configuration.  What am I missing?

Comment: Ah, you are right. I apologize. Although no 3 of the lines go through one of our chosen points, there can perfectly well be 3 or more through another point. My comment gives at most a bound on $k$.

Comment: There are many results known -- see "New applications of the polynomial method: The cap set conjecture and beyond" by Grochow for an overview

Comment: @Kevin:  Thank you.  This helps, both as a pointer to relevant literature and as a reassurance that I hadn't overlooked an utterly trivial solution.   But a (very) quick glance at Grochow suggests that all the results are for affine space, whereas my main interest is really in the projective case.  I wonder how much light the former sheds on the latter.

Comment: @Kevin:  I see now from a more careful look that Grochow references results on projective space as well.  This should be quite helpful.  Thanks again.